# Wordpress Navigation: Logo right, navigation left

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

i have this [website](http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) builted with Wordpress and a template based on Bootstrap. This template has a navigation on top and what i need is to "invert" the Brand (logo) and the navigation. Basically i need to float the logo right and the navigation left.

I tried via CSS but does not works.

Any tips?

Thanks in advice

EDIT: Navigation code

```
<div class="navigation" role="banner">
<div class="secondary-navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="contact">
</div>
<div class="user-area">
<div class="actions">
</div>

</div>


</div>
</div>  

<div class="container">
<header class="navbar" id="top">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand nav" href="http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/" title="Un nuovo sito targato WordPress" rel="home"><h1 class="site-title">W-Liestal</h1><h2 class="site-description">Un nuovo sito targato WordPress</h2></a>
</div>
<nav class="primary-navigation collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation" aria-label="Primary Navigation">
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav"><li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item"><a href="http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://#">Architektur</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://#">Ausstattung</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wohnen/">Wohnen</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/lage/">Lage</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://w-liestal.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/kontakt/">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>       
</nav>  
</header><!-- /.navbar -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.navigation -->
<!-- end Navigation -->
```

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of the navigation and logo?

Comment: @scemufessa,You need to enqueue script

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 :**

This is what you could do:

1 - Put the CSS code in a separate file  (mystyle.css) and save it in your theme directory.

2 - put the following code in your functions php:

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

**Case 2:**
 You Css version problem,

install plugin `wpquerystringmodifier` increase version. (simple way)

Other wise, find functions.php file and search style.

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri(),null,1.1.1,true );
```